# How to stop SQL query to sort itself in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, union

I wrote a simple query that gives a result in following format:

```
  Language
 _________
    ar
    en
    sb
```

The problem is that I didn't apply any sort order but it still sorted the result alphabetically in ascending order. How should I stop it?

Here is my query,

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM
 (
   SELECT template_lang_code AS "LANGUAGE_CODE" 
   FROM iris_cms.product_service_alerts 
   WHERE productid = '102161' 
   AND service_code = '6' 
   AND  template_lang_code = (SELECT paramvalue AS "LANGUAGE_CODE" 
                              FROM IRIS_CMS.tblcustomerdetail 
                              WHERE customerid = '6435635354' 
                              AND paramid = (SELECT entity_id 
                                             FROM IRIS_CMS.tblcfgdynamiccustomerform 
                                             WHERE control_id = 'LANGUAGE_CODE') 
                             AND paramvalue != '-1')
   UNION
   SELECT language_code 
   FROM iris_config.alert_template 
   WHERE template_id = (SELECT template_id 
                        FROM IRIS_CMS.product_service_alerts 
                        WHERE productid = '102161' 
                          AND service_code = '6' AND is_default = '1')
 )
 fetch FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

I want result to be in order of query, if 1st row in union has a value it should be at top and so on.

Comment: Sorting isn't guaranteed to be consistent without an explicit ORDER BY clause... If you don't want it sorted alphabetically you must have a sort order in mind. What sort order do you want?

Comment: if you don't sort by any column, the result is not sorted. BUT in your case you're using a UNION, which automatically has to sort to process the UNION.

Comment: @Ben I just want it be in sequence same as query is written, during union, 1st row result should be at the top and same for others.

Comment: Oracle Union function will automatically sort the column, use either an additional column for sort, or use union all

Comment: @EstebanP.: a `union` does **not** "automatically" sort the result (in fact it is very unlikely, because Oracle usually uses a hash algorithm to implement the implicit distinct which does not do any sorting at all)

Comment: @JohnHC: "use either an additional column for sort" => correct. "or use union all" => incorrect. While `UNION ALL` seems more appropriate here anyway, it doesn't guarantee any sort order; you'd still have to apply an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Oracle docs might be out of date then, they imply union all will apply ordering between q1 and q2, although will not order the results therein

Comment: Based on that you are limiting your result set to 1 row only, you are essentially saying: If the first select returns a value, that is what I want. If not, then get the value from the second select. So, you could rewrite the query to return 1 value, no union, based on the desired logic, and ordering will not matter one iota.

Comment: @PeterAbolins you got it right, let me try return solution too.

Answer (score 3):

The order you get when you don't specify an `order by` is non-deterministic. Especially together with `fetch first rows` you should always specify an `order by`.

If you want to give the rows from each part of the union a different "priority", you can do that by adding a column that you can use for sorting:

```
SELECT language_code
FROM
(
 SELECT template_lang_code AS "LANGUAGE_CODE", 
        1 as sort_order --<< HERE
 FROM ...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT language_code, 
        2   --<< HERE
 FROM ...
)
ORDER BY sort_order, language_code
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This sort all rows from the first part of the union at the top. Rows with the same language_code in the first part will be sorted alphabetically. All rows from the second part of the union will come after the rows of the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem , It seems you would like the result to be in random order rather than ordered alphabetically.

You can use the following Order By Statement which would Order by the globally unique identifier (GUID) in memory for each row and hence would be completely unordered.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: I don't want it in random order, I want it to be in order query is written for union, I think I should add this to question.

Comment: There is no function `newid()` in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. Essentially, the union is not necessary, given that only one row is wanted. The second part of the union can be reduced to a logical condition. And... sorting issues are no longer relevant.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM
 (
     SELECT template_lang_code AS "LANGUAGE_CODE" 
     FROM iris_cms.product_service_alerts 
     WHERE productid = '102161' 
         AND service_code = '6' 
         AND (template_lang_code = (SELECT paramvalue AS "LANGUAGE_CODE" 
                          FROM IRIS_CMS.tblcustomerdetail 
                          WHERE customerid = '6435635354' 
                          AND paramid = (SELECT entity_id 
                                         FROM IRIS_CMS.tblcfgdynamiccustomerform 
                                         WHERE control_id = 'LANGUAGE_CODE') 
                         AND paramvalue != '-1')
              OR is_default = '1')
 )
 fetch FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```